# Do I need to state a results type with AJAX Post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have code as follows, I have checked that all the variables in my JS match and are established, and all the variables in my data array in my AJAX match my $_POST['var']; tags in my php.  I added a line with
error:function(a,b,c){alert(a + b + c);}
to my ajax to try to figure out why it wouldn't return any html.
it returns "[OBJECT object]error" which doesn't tell me much.

When I run my php page with my php variables equal to numbers instead of $_POST['var']; and it runs fine.

MY question is on why won't this return my echoed html from my .php script?
Do I need to specify the returned data type to expect?

Thanks, J

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#results").click(function () {
        alert("1");
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.URL.com/go/php.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {ajaxval: HC1, 
                    bla: HCbl,
                    blka: HCblk,
                    bra: HCbr,
                    rda: HCrd,
                    za: HCz,
                    hla: HLa,
                    eca: ECa,
                    esa: ESa,
                    fsa: FSa,
                    hta: HTa,
                    btsa: BSa,
                    btra: BRa,
                    bbsa: BBSa,
                    bbfa: BBFa,
                    auga: AUGa,
                    agea: Aga,
                    hgta: Hta,
                    mta: MTa,
                    tha: THa,
                    sta: STa,
                    tata: PFa,
                    hcimpa: hci,
                    hlimpa: hli,
                    ecimpa: eci,
                    esimpa: esi,
                    fsimpa: fsi,
                    htimpa: hti,
                    bsimpa: bsi,
                    brimpa: bri,
                    bbsimpa: bbsi,
                    bbfimpa: bbfi,
                    augimpa: augi,
                    ageimpa: agei,
                    hgtimpa: Hti,
                    mtimpa: mti,
                    thimpa: thi,
                    stimpa: sti,
                    tatimpa: tati}
            }).done(function(data){ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data; alert("4"); });        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax has some a requirement of knowing what it is working with.  This is especially true when you start returning "Javascript Objects" to ajax responses.  So specifying a `dataType` is very much encouraged.

More can be explained here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

That said, take a look at this function which will help send and receive AJAX and while this function is designed to input "html" into a container... you can easily modify it to fit other needs.

http://pastebin.com/7nRrE2Jd